# In Godot, polygons disappear and randomly reappear. They are not displayed as I arranged them

Tags: shader, rendering, godot

I created a character using several polygons and placed them. I added bones. But as soon as I assigned a skeleton to the polygons, the limbs started disappearing, distorting, and scattering across the screen. What can be done? Is this related to the weakness of the GPU, and is it possible to do something other than replacing the hardware?
I have HD Graphics 4000, Godot 4.1. I run it from the command line using OpenGL 3, otherwise it won't launch as it requires Vulkan. There is a mesaInjector in the Godot folder.
An errors occur of the following type: "shader failed to compile, unable to bind shader"[as at screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzqDM.jpg)

[that's how it seem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhhq1.jpg)

I changed rendering modes, but it doesn't affect anything, everything remains the same.

Comment: It looks like that similar issue https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/76142 - the advice is to switch to Godot 4.2 and use the ANGLE backend.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have `Rest Pose` specified for the Skeleton node. Without Rest Pose some editor features does not work properly. Select skeleton node and assign Rest Pose. Later you will be able to overwrite it, when you position bones as you wish.
2. Assign weights to the bones. Select a polygon, then open `UV` editor, press `Bones` button to switch to weight paint mode, and you'll see vertices of your mesh - when there is no weight assigned then the vertex looks black, and when 100% weight assigned, the vertex is white. Select a bone in the left side list (if the list is empty then do "Sync Bones to Polygon"). Then select a bone you wish to affect the mesh and use brush/cursor to paint wanted vertices.

Check as example this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CA5oSM6f0fo

Comment: Thank you, dhargo.
All that I tried.
Doing "Sync Bones to Polygon" causes the issue)